# electron - electron-builder auto-updater update.yml not found?

Tags: electron

Im now using `electron-builder` and managed to get to the point where the event listeners are setup and firing, but I don't think I have it fully setup right as when I open the app using `electron .`, I get the following error:

```
Checking for update
Cannot check for updates:
Error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'C:\Users\Shiny\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\app-update.yml'
```

I do get the `app-update.yml` file, but instead its being generated to:
`E:\Projects\3DS-Files\dist\win-ia32-unpacked\resources`
*(Which is where my github repository is)*

If I manually put the file there it will actually try and check for updates, I havent tested if it can actually download the update but its actually trying atleast.
**What's going wrong?**

---

And when its installed its being generated to:
`C:\Users\Shiny\AppData\Local\Programs\3DS-Files\resources`

The scripts to build that im using is:

```
"scripts": {
  "b:win": "build -w --ia32 --dir",
  "p:win": "build -w --ia32"
},
"build": {
    "appId": "3dsfiles",
    "mac": {
      "category": "3dsfiles"
    },
    "win": {
      "publish": "github",
      "iconUrl": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/initPRAGMA/3DS-Files/master/build/icon.ico"
    }
  },
```

**(You can find my full package.json [here](http://pastebin.com/raw/WN7d9PqV))**

b:win simply builds it, p:win packages it into an NSIS installer.
**Maybe im missing a command?**

---

The index.js (The interesting bit) is:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, shell, dialog} = require('electron')
const {autoUpdater} = require('electron-auto-updater')
const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')

autoUpdater.addListener("update-available", function(event) {
  dialog.showMessageBox({ title: "A new update is ready to install", message: `Version ${it.version} is downloaded and will be automatically installed on Quit`, buttons: ["OK"] });
});
autoUpdater.addListener("update-downloaded", function(event, releaseNotes, releaseName, releaseDate, updateURL) {
  autoUpdater.quitAndInstall();
});
autoUpdater.addListener("error", function(error) {
  dialog.showMessageBox({ title: "Error Happened", message: error, buttons: ["OK"] });
});
autoUpdater.addListener("checking-for-update", function(event) {
  dialog.showMessageBox({ title: "Checking for update", message: `:l`, buttons: ["OK"] });
});
autoUpdater.addListener("update-not-available", function(event) {
  dialog.showMessageBox({ title: "No update available", message: `:l`, buttons: ["OK"] });
});
```

I havent set it up to do proper actions or anything, just a simple messagebox for debugging which obviously isnt the best way to do it, but its quick and simple.
**Maybe im missing some functions?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to file issue to electron-builder project.

It seems, you are trying to use auto-update not for packed app (after installation), but directly from unpacked (e.g. from `win-ia32-unpacked`).

Comment: Your right, thats perfectly why! Thanks! It works fine when I actually install it :)

Comment: How you solved this. Can you please explain.